# SoapClient : Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I try to use SoapClient with cafile, local_cert and local_pk

```
function __construct($wsdl,$pem,$key,$cert){
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            "ssl" => array(
                'verify_peer'      => false,
                'verifyhost '      => false,
                "cafile"           => $cert,
                'local_cert'       => $pem,
                'local_pk'         => $key
            )
        )
    );

    $this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('soap_version'    => SOAP_1_2,
                                                'local_cert'      => $pem,
                                                'trace'           => true,
                                                'context'  => $context
                                               ));
}
```

but I catch this error : **Could not connect to host**

my wsdl is a document style and he using literal.

When I dump the soap object :

```
object(SoapClient)[19]
  public 'trace' => int 1
  ``public _stream_context' => resource(38, stream-context)
  public '_soap_version' => int 2
  public 'sdl' => resource(39, SOAP SDL)
```

Comment: I try with curl command, and its work but with SoapClient no .. :C

Answer (score 0):

```
$context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            "ssl" => array(
                'verify_peer' => true,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                "cafile"           => $cert,
                'local_cert'       => $pem,
                'local_pk'         => $key
            )
        )
```

Its work C: